# Adding static block in home page of magento

Tags: magento

I want to show 5 categories "mobile" "laptop" best selleing products","","" from my product listing page to home page..

How to call multiple static blocks in home page...

i have created   a static block named mobile and in content i have written the code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="43"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

after that i called that block in template page...

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('mobile')->toHtml() ?>
```

i can only call 1 static block unable to display multiple static blocks....

How can i display?

Comment: Either ways you can add a single static block and include the content of all the blocks in it.

Comment: i tried it its not showing....only 1 block displaying..not more than 1

Comment: Magento's static block contains data input-ed by user. You can insert all your data for 5 blocks in HTML form in that single block 'mobile' and call it on frontend.

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="43"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="23"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
 its not diasplying....whats the problem? but it is working fine if i write only 1 statement

Comment: i also tried of creating multiple static blocks and calling them multiple times in template page but its not working

Answer (score 8):

just go to admin->cms->page->design-layout page, and update the layout

```
 <reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_list" name="mobile" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
</block>

  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="laptop" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
</block>

</reference>
```

OR

write that code to admin->cms->page->content

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: in the above code what are the things i should change and copy

Comment: category ids, to your own category ids, for mobile and laptop

Comment: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 314013310

Comment: enable the error printing, so we could find what the error is. rename the file to local.xml from error/local.xml.sample

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: bUT ITS WORKING FINE IF I ADD only 1 block i.e<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_list" name="mobile" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
</block></reference>

Comment: i have updated the answer, paste that code in cms->page->content

Comment: asif hhh  <reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_list" name="mobile" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
</block>

  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="laptop" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
</block>

</reference>  This code is working now...but the last category id is repeating.so please check it

Comment: did you added your own ids ? inplace of 2 and 3 ?

Comment: if i add 23 and 23 2 blocks repeating

Comment: have you tried with other then 43, might be issue with 43. add something 23 and 25 just to test it. if still error then give it a try with my answer after OR

Comment: if i add 2 different category id some sql error showing... and i tried or part its not working..the code is being dispalyed  entirely on homepage

Comment: OR part: your WYSIWYG editor is on, save content by disabling it

Comment: OR part is working now but the same old problem continues i.e only 1 block is able to dispay..if i add 2 block codes all blocks disappear

Comment: which Magento ver you are using ?